# Stable Diffusion XL is two separate models - how do I use it to generate images?

Tags: image-generation, stable-diffusion, comfyui

SDXL 1.0 just released and, unlike previous Stable Diffusion releases, appears to be made up of two separate models - a "base" and a "refiner":

- https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0
- https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-refiner-1.0

Most workflows I can see are designed for previous releases and only load a single checkpoint - how should I load and perform inference with these two models?

Answer (score 4):

To make full use of SDXL, you'll need to load in both models, run the base model starting from an empty latent image, and then run the refiner on the base model's output to improve detail.

In [ComfyUI](https://github.com/comfyanonymous/ComfyUI) this can be accomplished with the output of one KSampler node (using SDXL base) leading directly into the input of another KSampler node (using SDXL refiner, for the final steps). The first KSampler node should have `return_with_leftover_noise` enabled:

[image: Workflow diagram]

Output image (contains metadata, can be downloaded and dragged into ComfyUI to load the workflow):
[image: Generated image of a bottle]
([source with more info](https://comfyanonymous.github.io/ComfyUI_examples/sdxl/))

As opposed to regular SD which was used with a resolution of 512x512, SDXL should be used at 1024x1024.

---

For frontends that don't support chaining models like this, or for faster speeds/lower VRAM usage, the SDXL base model alone can still achieve good results:

[image: https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-0.9/media/main/comparison.png]
([source](https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0))

The refiner has only been trained to denoise small noise levels, so shouldn't be used without the base.

Comment: I read that the base model should operate on 512x512 and the refiner upscales it to 1024x1024 (or bigger). But the Comfy-UI seems to execute the base on a 1024x1024 image. I think this is probably less efficient?

Comment: @Falco Do you have a link where that's said? As far as I can find, refiner and base both operate at 1024x1024 pixels (which internally in latent space will be a 128x128 tensor, but frontends handle that for you).  [An official inference demo has the same.](https://github.com/Stability-AI/generative-models/blob/45c443b316737a4ab6e40413d7794a7f5657c19f/scripts/demo/sampling.py#L38). Other similar-enough resolutions also reportedly work well.

Comment: You are right, I've remembered it wrong from the beta-phase. The 1.0 Release seems to operate on 1024x1024 in the base model as well.